# unable to call different class after index in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I just started learning codeigniter and came up with some problem I could not sort.

In routing the default controller = 'home'

the base_url()=localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/:

So when the site is loaded the site_url()=localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php

Home controller contains a link , to register controller.

So when this register controller is inside home object, and when the  is linked to localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/register it works fine.

But I want to make my Register controller a different object so that, I can go to register page like this localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/register which I cannot get done. I tried messing with 'routes' but no luck there. Any Ideas?

Comment: Read documentation, or search how to remove index.php from url in codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create in your root directory a .htaccess file with following rules to use URI segments on routing properly :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

more at [codeigniter documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)

Comment: I did the .htaaccess and yet The requested URL /CodeIgniter_2.1.3/register was not found on this server. Going to read the docs. EDIT: The htaccess thing worked when I refreshed the page twice [should be the cache]. Thanks for your help.